# How to match previous character of in a string using regex

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, preg-match

Lets say i have this string `Â§cHi there`

I want to use regex to match `Â§c` so I can extract the message.
The way I want it to work is it looks for `§` and then match the next **and** the previous character.
So far I am able to match the next character by this expression `[§].{1}`.

My question is how to match the privious character which is `Â`.

Comment: You can just specify `Â§c`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First match `.[§].`, then take the first and third character of the match.

Note: your example regex `[§].{1}` is the same as `[§].`

`.` matches any character (sometimes with the exception of the newline character)